# Android: How to (re)use LayoutInflater

Tags: android, performance

I'm wondering how to properly obtain a `LayoutInflater` instance and how long to keep it around.

The android doc states:

> It is never used directly. Instead, use getLayoutInflater() or
>   getSystemService(String) to retrieve a standard LayoutInflater
>   instance that is already hooked up to the current context and
>   correctly configured for the device you are running on.

My questions:

- Is getSystemService(String) fast so I can call it everywhere i need an instance?
- Should i store the inflater-instance in a variable for later use?
- I think I saw some interfaces in the SDK, that pass `LayoutInflater`, why do they do that?

Comment: don't forget you can use LayoutInflater.from(Context c) to get a reference. It's just a cleaner code than casting stuff to LayoutInflater.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is getSystemService(String) fast so I can call it everywhere i need an instance?

AFAIK, yes, though you may want to run a test and examine the method trace in Traceview to confirm.

> Should i store the inflater-instance in a variable for later use?

If you are in a tight loop, hang onto the instance in a local variable versus creating calling `getLayoutInflater()` each time. Otherwise, I am not aware that it is a worthwhile optimization.

> I think I saw some interfaces in the SDK, that pass LayoutInflater, why do they do that?

To save you the trouble of calling `getLayoutInflater()`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is getSystemService(String) fast so I can call it everywhere i need an
>   instance?

You can also use `inflater = LayoutInflator.from(this);` to retrieve the inflater. I personally find less code to write using this method.

> Should i store the inflater-instance in a variable for later use?

It's fine to store in a local variable.